# Sage symbolic variables and +=

Tags: sage

When I substitute symbolic variables x1, x2 into a function, the sum notation "+=" (in the function definition) does not allow them because it only accepts reals. Therefore it spits out a TypeError. I need to substitute symbolic variables into the function. Is there any workaround?

---update:---

I have tried replacing += with sum() without breaking my function, something like `M[i,j] = sum([L[i]/(L[i]-L[k]) for k in range(n) if i != k])`. When substituting x1 x2, it spits out the same error: `TypeError: unable to convert x1/(x1 - x2) to a rational`

Here's my attempt:

```
x1,x2 = var('x1 x2')

A2 = Afunction(2, [x1,x2]) 
#Afunction takes an integer n and a list as the inputs, the output is a n by n matrix
```

Comment: Please provide more details, for example the definition of `Afunction`. If your `M` is a matrix with rational entries, for example defined by `M = matrix(QQ, 3, 3)`, then in `M[i,j] = ...`, the right side should be a rational or convertible to a rational. Maybe that's the issue? Certainly `+=` allows the use of symbolic variables, as in `var('x, y'); a = 0; a += x; a += 3*y`.

Comment: Thanks again, you are right the problem is with my matrix definition in particular "QQ"!!

Comment: I was just reading an article written by you (Sage tutorial)!

Comment: It was a group effort: I helped, I didn't write the whole thing. I hope it's useful!